Why Google Cloud API Access Token expires in 7 days?
I have setup Google Cloud service to access the Google Analytics data through the API in Azure pipelines. I used the Azure pipelines because I want to automate the process so that no manual intervention is needed. It works great with one problem. The access token expires in 7 days. Further investigating, I found it is because my cloud server is configured as Publishing Status = Testing. I can publish my services to get 6 months of token life but then, it raises some security concerns too. I am wondering if there's a way to extend the life of access token from 7 days to one months or so while keeping the publishing status to Testing mode. Any related inputs are welcome.
